# How to force full page navigation rather than virtual page navigation in SPA

Tags: javascript, jquery, backbone.js, single-page-application

We have a single page application and we just want to ensure that the user will always be working with the latest version of the web app.

Our simple, although hacky solution, is to detect all anchor clicks and check if the time since page load >= 24 hours. If it is we want to perform a 'full page' navigation rather than a 'virtual page' navigation. Ie, instead of going to `#contact-us` with no page refresh, we want to send the user to `http://website.com#contact-us` where a page refresh will occur.

In the function below I can detect a 'virtual' navigation that is about to be performed. But how can I then force a full page navigation and refresh? Should I change the anchor href attribute to the full website path then allow the event to propagate? Or should I just do `window.location = ...;`?

```
events: {
        'click a[href!=""]': 'onClick'
}

onClick: function(ev) 
{
    try {

        var now                     = new Date()
        ,   hoursSinceLastRefresh   = Math.abs(now - this.lastRefresh) / 36e5
        ,   href                    = ev.currentTarget.attr('href')
        ,   isVirtualNavigation     = href.substr(0,1) === '#'
        ,   pageExpired             = hoursSinceLastRefresh >= 24;

        // if is internal navigation
        if (isVirtualNavigation && pageExpired)
            // How can I force a 'full page' navigation not a virtual navigation?

    }
    catch (ex) {

    }
}
```

PS: what are the proper terms for the following:

- When a user clicks the link `<a href="#contact-us">` the page does not refresh but the user 'navigates' to a new page in the SPA. Whats the term for this? I've been calling this 'virtual page' navigation.
- When a user clicks the link `<a href="http://website.com#contact-us">` the page does refresh in the SPA. Whats the term for this? I've been calling this 'full page' navigation.

*Note* Our `<link ..>` and `<script ...>` elements have timestamp parameters so upon page refresh they will pull the latest web application files. Ie, `<script src="foo.js?t=201706031200" ...>`.

Comment: Clicking on an anchor tag triggers a [hashchange event](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowEventHandlers/onhashchange)  

Actively navigating to another page triggers a [popstate event](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Events/popstate) (among other things).   

Perhaps take a look at docs around [Window.location](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/location). It might give you some ideas.

Answer (score 0):

```js
events: {
        'click a[href!=""]': 'onClick'
}

onClick: function(ev) 
{
    try {

        var now                     = new Date()
        ,   hoursSinceLastRefresh   = Math.abs(now - this.lastRefresh) / 36e5
        ,   href                    = ev.currentTarget.attr('href')
        ,   isVirtualNavigation     = href.substr(0,1) === '#'
        ,   pageExpired             = hoursSinceLastRefresh >= 24;

        // if is internal navigation
        if (isVirtualNavigation && pageExpired){
          href.reload(true);
        }
    }
    catch (ex) {

    }
}
```

Comment: thanks for your comment and answer. Wouldn't `href.reload(true)` reload the current page and not the page the user is trying to navigate to?

Comment: I don't believe so, because aren't you setting `var href` to be the value of the href attribute of the anchor tag that is being clicked when you do:  

`href  = ev.currentTarget.attr('href')` ?

Answer (score 0):

Just do a `window.location=...` and the browser will do the rest ;)